# How evaluate $ \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2\;\left|\;\tan\left(\frac{ax}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\;\right|}{1+x^2} \;dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

How evaluate (without using Complex analysis)
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2\;\left|\;\tan\left(\frac{ax}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\;\right|}{1+x^2}\; dx\quad (a\gt0)$$

My Attempt:
I used the expansion of the following functions: $$ \ln\left|2\sin(x)\right| \text{ and }\ln\left|2\cos(x)\right| $$
To get the following expansion: $$ \ln\;\left|\;\tan\left(\frac{ax}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\;\right|=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\sin[(2n-1)ax]}{2n-1} $$
Then I expressed the square of the logarithmic function as follows:$$ \ln^2\;\left|\;\tan\left(\frac{ax}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\;\right|=4\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+n} \frac{\sin[(2m-1)ax]\sin[(2n-1)ax]}{(2m-1)(2n-1)} $$
And used the formula of the product of two sines, then integrated the following well known integral under the summation sign:
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(bx)}{1+x^2} \;dx$$
And expressed the final result in terms of $\; \arctan\;\left(\;e^{-a}\;\right)\; $
but this was not the right answer according to the one evaluated by Complex analysis, which is
$$ \frac{{\pi}^3}{8}-2\pi\; \arctan^2\;\left(\;e^{-a}\;\right) $$
Any hint for another method or idea?

Comment: It is relevant that $\log|\tan(x/2-\pi/4)| = -i(\arctan(e^{-ix}) - \arctan(e^{ix}) ) $
$=-2i(\arctan(e^{\pm ix} ) \mp \pi/4)$ where in the last formula the sign is $+$ if $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2, -\pi/2 + 2\pi < x < \pi/2 + 2\pi, ...$ and the $-$ sign otherwise.  Your stated answer is $2\pi( (\pi/4)^2 - \arctan^2(e^{-a} )) $ which seems to scream to use the observation with the residue theorem. However, by problem statement, it is not allowed.

Comment: @skbmoore, thx for the insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using OP's series expansion, we have

\begin{align*}
I
&= 2 \sum_{m, n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(2m+1)(2n+1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin[(2m+1)ax]\sin[(2n+1)ax]}{1+x^2} \, dx \\
&= \pi \sum_{m, n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(2m+1)(2n+1)} \left( e^{-a|2m-2n|} - e^{-a(2m+2n+2)} \right).
\end{align*}

We will split the sum into several parts and analyze them separately.

- It is straightforward that

  $$ \sum_{m, n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(2m+1)(2n+1)} e^{-a(2m+2n+2)} = \arctan^2(e^{-a}). $$
- Using the identity $\frac{1}{(2m+1)(2n+1)} = \frac{1}{(2m-2n)(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{(2n-2m)(2m+1)}$, we have

  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{m, n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(2m+1)(2n+1)} e^{-a|2m-2n|}
  &= \sum_{m = 0} \frac{1}{(2m+1)^2} + \sum_{\substack{m, n \geq 0 \\ m \neq n }} \frac{(-1)^{m-n}}{(m-n)(2n+1)} e^{-a|2m-2n|} \\
  &= \frac{\pi^2}{8} + \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{2n+1} \sum_{\substack{k \geq -n \\ k \neq 0}} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} e^{-2a|k|}.
  \end{align*}
- The last sum can be simplified further: using the fact that $\frac{(-1)^k}{k}e^{-2a|k|}$ is an odd function of $k$,

  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{2n+1} \sum_{\substack{k \geq -n \\ k \neq 0}} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} e^{-2a|k|}
  &= \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{2n+1} \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} e^{-2a|k|} \\
  &= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{2n+1} \right) \frac{(-1)^k}{k} e^{-2a|k|}.
  \end{align*}

  Symmetrizing the inner sum, we find that

  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{2n+1}
  = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\substack{i, j \geq 0 \\ i+j = k-1}} \left( \frac{1}{2i+1} + \frac{1}{2j+1} \right)
  = \sum_{\substack{i, j \geq 0 \\ i+j = k-1}} \frac{k}{(2i+1)(2j+1)}.
  \end{align*}

  Plugging this back,

  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{2n+1} \sum_{\substack{k \geq -n \\ k \neq 0}} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} e^{-2a|k|}
  &= \sum_{i, j \geq 0} \frac{1}{(2i+1)(2j+1)} (-1)^{i+j+1} e^{-a(2i+2j+2)} \\
  &= - \arctan^2(e^{-a}).
  \end{align*}

Combining altogether, we obtain the desired answer.

Comment: Brilliant sir. The summation technicues used in the 2nd part of your answer are fabulous.

Comment: I'll wait another day and accept your solution.

Comment: Just one inquiry, I got the swapping of indexes step, I got the symmeterizing step, but the last step where you replaced $k$ with $i+j+1$ how did you remove the inner sum? Also, there was a restriction $i+j=k-1$

Comment: @Wolfdale, I merged the outer sum and the inner sum. This follows by noting that $$\{(i,j) : i,j \geq 0\} = \bigsqcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \{ (i,j) : i,j \geq 0 \text{ and } i+j = k-1 \},$$ where the right-hand side is the disjoint union. (Perhaps it is easier to visualize this from $ij$-plane, where $i+j=k-1$ is the line joining $(0,k-1)$ and $(k-1,0)$ and hence this line sweeps all the lattice points $(i,j)$ with $i,j \geq 0$ exactly once by varying $k$.)

Comment: Thx for the clarification. One final question, what is your opinion about using the expantion of $\ln\left|\tan\left(\frac{ax}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right|$, there is a restriction $\frac{-\pi}{2}\lt ax \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$, and we integrated $f(x)$ over $\mathbb {R}^+$?

Comment: @Wolfdale, The expansion is valid on all of $\mathbb{R}$ except for zeros and poles of $\tan(\frac{ax}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4})$. Of course we have to justify interchanging the order of summation and integration, which I did not attempt in my answer above. But given the integrability of logarithmic singularities, I think it won't be a serious problem.

Answer (score 2):

part(1)
$$first\ part\\
I=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{ln^2(tan(\frac{ax}{2}-\frac{\pi }{4}))}{x^2+1}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{ln^2(cot(\frac{ax}{2}-\frac{\pi }{4}))}{x^2+1}dx\\
\\
we\ have\ ln^2(cot(\frac{ax}{2}-\frac{\pi }{4})=-2\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{m+n}\frac{sin(2m-1)ax.sin(2n-1)ax}{(2m-1)(2n-1))}\\
\\
 =2\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{m+n}[cos(2m-2n)ax-cos(2m+2nax))]}{(2m-1)(2n-1)}\\
\\
\therefore I=\frac{\pi }{2}\sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(2m-1)(2n-1)}[e^{-2a(2m-2n)}-e^{-2a(2m+2n-2)}]\\
\\
note\ \sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(2m-1)(2n-1)}e^{-2a(2n+2m-2)}\\
\\
=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(2m-1)}e^{-2a(2m-1)}.\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)}e^{-2a(2n-1)}=arctan^2(e^{-2a})$$

second  part 
$$second\ part \\
\because \sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(2m-1)(2n-1)}e^{-2a(2m-2n)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}+\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{m-n}}{(2m-1)(2n-1)}e^{-2a(2m-2n)}\\
\\
=\frac{\pi ^{3}}{8}+\sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{m-n}}{(m-n)(2n-1)}e^{-2a(2m-2n)}=\frac{\pi ^{3}}{8}+\sum_{n>=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n-1)}.\sum_{n,m>=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{m-n}}{(m-n)}e^{-2a|2m-2a}\\
\\
=\frac{\pi ^{3}}{8}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2n-1}.\sum_{k=n}^{\infty }e^{-4a|k|}\Rightarrow k=m-n\\
\\
=\frac{\pi ^{3}}{8}+\sum_{k=n}^{\infty }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}e^{-4ak}=\frac{\pi ^{3}}{8}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }[\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2n-1}]\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}e^{-4ak}$$

part(3)
$$third \ part\\
but\ 2\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2n-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2i-1}+\sum_{g=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2g-1}\\
\\
=\sum _{i+g=k+1}(\frac{1}{2i-1}+\frac{1}{2g-1})=\sum _{i+g=k+1}\frac{2(i+g-1)}{(2i-1)(2g-1))}\\
\therefore \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2n-1}=\sum _{i+g=k+1}\frac{k}{(2i-1)(2g-1))}\\
\therefore \sum _{k>=1}[\sum _{i+g=k+1}\frac{k}{(2g-1)(2i-1)}]e^{-2a(2m-2n)}=-\sum _{i,g>=1}\frac{(-1)^{i-g}}{(2i-1)(2g-1)}e^{-2a(2i+2g-2)}\\
\\
=-arctan^2(e^{-2a})\ \ \ \ \ \ so \ we \ have\  I=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{ln^2(cot(\frac{ax}{2}))-\frac{\pi }{4})}{x^2+1}dx\\
\\
=\frac{\pi ^{3}}{16}-\pi arctan^2(e^{-2a})\\
\\
\therefore I=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{ln^2(cot(\frac{ax}{2})-\frac{\pi }{4})}{x^2+4}dx =\frac{\pi ^{3}}{8}-2\pi arctan^2 (e^{-2a})\\
\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ahmed\ hegazi$$